# How unused default member initializer can change program behavior in C++?

Tags: c++, c++20, aggregate-initialization

Please consider this short code example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A() { std::cout << "A() "; }
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A() "; }
};

struct B { const A &a; };

struct C { const A &a = {}; };

int main()
{
    B b({});
    std::cout << ". ";

    C c({});
    std::cout << ". ";
}
```

GCC prints here ( https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/czWrq8G5j )

```
A() ~A() . A() . ~A()
```

meaning that the lifetime of `A`-object initializing reference in `b` is short, but in `c` the lifetime is prolonged till the end of the scope.

The only difference between structs `B` and `C` is in default member initializer, which is *unused* in main(), still the behavior is distinct. Could you please explain why?

Comment: If it actually prints it then it is a bug in compiler.

Comment: Another vote for a GCC bug, the code doesn't even compile in MSVC or clang

Comment: @AlanBirtles: Compiles with MSVC [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cEezoq39G). and it is a C++20 features (aggregate initialization with `()`), that clang doesn't support yet, see [compiler_support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) (Parenthesized initialization of aggregates).

Comment: @Jarod42, should the C++20 tag be added to the question?

Comment: Yes, good point

Comment: But seems a bug anyway as aggregate-initialization with `{}` gives different [result](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aPqGMx79v).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C c(...);` is syntax for direct  initialisation. Overload resolution would find a match from the constructors of `C`: The move constructor can be called by temporary materialisation of a `C` from `{}`. `{}` is value initialisation which will use the default member initialiser. Thus, the default member initialiser isn't unused. Since C++17, the move constructor isn't necessary and `{}` initialises variable `c` directly; In this case `c.a` is bound directly to the temporary `A` and the lifetime is extended until destruction of `C`.

`B` isn't default constructible, so the overload resolution won't find a match. Instead, aggregate initialisation is used since C++20 - prior to that it would be ill-formed. The design of the C++20 feature is to not change behaviour of previously valid programs, so aggregate initialisation has lower priority than the move constructor.

Unlike in the case of `C`, the lifetime of the temporary `A` isn't extended because parenthesised initialisation list is an exceptional case. It would be extended if you used curly braces:

```
B b{{}};
```

Comment: but `B{{}}` doesn't behave as `B({})` [Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sveT59177)

Comment: Looks like correct explanation. Based on it, I eliminated ```C```-object default initialization and the result is consistent now: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3GxE3qqh5 Thanks

Comment: The `()` form does not lifetime-extend temporaries. See https://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6.10

Comment: @T.C. Thanks. Then the behaviour of the compiler is correct.